# Get SMS template name using ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, mobileconnect

Is it possible to get the mobile connect SMS template name using ampscript?

I cannot seem to find any article that has this use case though I found something for email using the Email data strings. I was hoping that there is something available for sms as well

Comment: This question might be useful. In your case you would need to pull in the firstname from the Data Extension - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/122185/ampscript-in-sms-how-to-use-dynamic-content-in-sms-with-ampscript-mobileconne

Comment: hi Jordan, what I actually need is the name of the sms template itself which is not stored in any data extension. I know its possible in email using %%emailname_%% or emailname_ Would you know any approach to get that in SMS perspective