# Use of data extension fields dynamically inside a SMS content

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Can we use a data extension fields dynamically inside a SMS content in marketing cloud. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes - similar as you would do in emails or cloud pages. Can you be more precise in what you are trying to achieve and where you are stuck?

Comment: What is the sending audience? List? DE? Journey

Comment: The sending audience is a data extension

Answer (score 1):

To use Data Extension fields in SMS for personalization, use the AMPscript Lookup function, as you would do in an email: https://ampscript.guide/lookup/

Bare in mind, that the `MOBILE_NUMBER` is the subscriber key for SMS subscribers.

Here’s an example of a lookup function for use in SMS:

```
%%[

set @lookupValue = MOBILE_NUMBER
set @fn = Lookup("DataExtensionName","FirstName","MobileNumber", @lookupValue)

]%%
First Name: %%=v(@fn)=%%
```

Here is a question similar to yours: [Personalization in Mobile Connect SMS called within Journey Builder](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/75986/personalization-in-mobile-connect-sms-called-within-journey-builder)